# A problem on limits using a rational function .

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $$f(x)= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^{2n-1} +ax^3+ bx^2}{x^{2n}+1}$$ is continuous for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$. If points $A(-a,3)$ and $B((b+1),-1)$ are points of relative maximum and minimum of a cubic polynomial $y=g(x)$, then what is the value of $g(2)$ ?

**My attempt**
I checked for the continuity of the function at $x=1$. Now $f(1)=\frac{a+b+1}2$ . Then I calculated $f(1^+)$ which comes out to be **1**. After equating $f(1)$ and $f(1^+)$ I got $a+b=1$.

I am stuck after this step because , I am not able to calculate the left hand limit at $x=1$ ,which might give me another relation of a and b . Please help in solving this question .

Comment: Why is this a very good problem?

Comment: I get $f(1) = (1 + a + b)/2$ too, and the graph of $f(x)$ is smooth above $x=1$.  (Yes... explain why this is "a very good problem."). Also, please write an *informative* title... one that deals with the core of the issue at hand.  Your title could refer to an immensely broad class of problems.

Comment: I asked first. ${}$

Comment: I can't think of any other title :(  @copper.hat

Comment: Oooh... very disappointing.

Comment: You can calculate the left-hand limit quite simply. Note that $x^{2n} \to 0$ and $x^{2n - 1} \to 0$, so the limit works out to be $a + b$. So you get $a + b = 1$, which doesn't help you. You need to consider a different point to take limits at.

Comment: I have no idea where else could use the condition for continuity . @MarkSaving